# Truncating text in UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I don't know why the text is getting truncated in the `UIAlertController`.
I don't know what I could have done.
Have I changed any settings unintentionally in `Xcode`?

```
let title = "Erro ao verificar usuário no servidor"
let message = "Não foi possível atualizar os dados. Tente novamente mais tarde"
let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
alert.addAction(ok)
present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image: Screenshots]

Comment: On wich device did you get the problem?

Comment: I've copied the code into an empty new project and it works all fine in any device simulator. This code itself doesn't seem to be your problem. Are there any overrides in your code or modifications to anything? I've read about truncated alert messages after modifications were done in functions and other things connected to the UIAlertController.

Comment: @Charles-olivierDemers on all devices of xcode simulator and in my physical iPhone-6

Comment: @Rodrigo Can you share us all the content of your file? Because like Aeger said, I was not able to reproduce the problem

Comment: I found the problem! I was using a UILabel extension to include padding in text. When I removed this, the UIAlertController works ok.

Comment: Rodrigo, you should post the solution that you found as an answer and then accept it so others can learn from it, and so that it is clear that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the problem! I was using a UILabel extension to include padding in text. When I removed this, the UIAlertController works ok.